# Is there a law against hotels denying guests to have visitors

Tags: legal, hotels, etiquette

I've been staying at a hotel for a few weeks now. When I checked into the room the clerk at the desk said that I can't have visitors. A few days later a gentlemen came to ask about something and said he was visiting his daughter who was staying at the hotel. It was as often completely ignored his question and said she has to leave for having a visitor. The gentleman was a retired federal agent and said that was against the law to do that. What's up with that? Is this true or what?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you did not include a country, I would read this Q as 'world wide' and that makes it very broad. If you can narrow this Q to one country and maybe even one state within that one country it might be possible to answer this question. If it is not narrowed down it will likely be closed. And if it is seen as a duplicate of an other question it will likely also be closed. That is not against you but to keep the site clean.

Comment: @Willeke, when someone doesn't bother to specify his country, as if it's completely obvious which one it is, he can only be American.

Comment: @ugoren, often true but I have seen cases of people from other countries, the most recent likely Malaysia.